# Shopify Custom storefront with laravel

Tags: php, shopify

I am totally new to shopify. What i want to achieve is create a client side 
(customer facing) to use my custom frontend designs and everything related to customers action (authentication, signup, order placement, payment etc etc) should be taken care by laravel by hitting the shopify's api. is something like this possible?

What i have read so far provides us with javascript API for custom storefront. I am not sure what i am trying to achieve is possible at least

are there any right approach to do this ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Shopify, but it should all be possible so long as your have access to the Shopify API endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your App to transact payments, authenticate customers (with Shopify).

You may want to apply your skills to using the Javascript Storefront API to make a custom storefront, if you really cannot see yourself using native Shopify Liquid.

Answering a question with a question. Why do you think your App could even approach basic Shopify in terms of performance, security or ease of maintenance for your merchant client? If you want to invent your own platform, by all means, but your questions seems polar opposite to why so many people choose Shopify platform, ie) getting rid of the problems that plague roll your own code bases.